# How do I get a jpg of a webpage (video element only not the entire screen) of a webpage using WebView2?

Tags: javascript, c#, webview

I am trying to grab the video element of a webpage and save the image locally.

In my code I have in my C# project:

```
this.webView.Source = new Uri( localhost:4000/watcher.html );
```

I'm running a local node server with javascript to display a video of a camera feed and in my watcher.html it looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Viewer</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="controls">
      <button id="button" onClick="changeCamera(0)">Camera One</button>   
      <button id="button2" onClick="changeCamera(1)">Camera Two</button>
    </div>
    
    <video playsinline autoplay muted></video>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="watch.js"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```

My c# project loads the webpage fine, but How can I grab a picture of the video element and not get the entire screen? I created the following function below to take a picture of the entire screen just to test, it works, but I have no clue on how I can manipulate the webView2 to get my image. Any input on how to achieve this would be amazing. Thanks.

```
private void TakePicture(string fileName)
{
    Bitmap screenGrab = new Bitmap( Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb );
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage( screenGrab );
    g.CopyFromScreen( Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Left, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Top, 0, 0, screenGrab.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy );
    screenGrab.Save( fileName + ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg );
}
```

P.S. I already explored trying to export the jpeg directly from my node server, I spent many many hours trying to get it to work and now I'm exploring other options.

Comment: If there's another way to capture a picture of the video element of the webpage that could also be very helpful.